Why is connection to port 443 denied when netstat suggests it's open?
The objective is to have a local development website accessible with https://castle. It can be accessed with http://... (The site in Windows 10 with latest Apache server, etc.) I've followed these instructions to create proper local authorities. But when they failed I drilled down as below.
What's known:

Firewall has open port 443 inbound and outbound
Failure occurs with self-signed certificate too
telnet 192.168.1.69 443 yields Connecting To 192.168.1.69...Could not open connection to the host, on port 443: Connect failed, which is the host of the website
IGNORE THIS: netstat -a -n -o | findstr /i "443" includes TCP    192.168.1.69:51399     192.168.1.73:443       CLOSE_WAIT      5400, which is an HP printer
openssl s_client -connect castle:443 yields 1916:error:0200274D:system library:connect:reason(1869):../openssl-1.1.1s/crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:110: and 1916:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:../openssl-1.1.1s/crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:111:

Clearly I'm missing something. What might that be?

there's no indication that 192.168.1.69 is listening on port 443 - your netstat output shows that port 443 is open on 192.168.1.73, which you say is a HP printer

Fair statement. Consider it eliminated. Failure remains.

well, if apache isn't listening on port 443, then you need to configure it to do so - not sure how the link "Enabling HTTPS for localhost in your Node.js development environment" will help with configuring Apache though

OOPS. I grabbed the wrong link for instructions. It now points to a medium.com page on creating certificates. Development is in Apache and HTML only.

Apache includes LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so and two others. But before Apache I would think I could telnet to port 443 but as shown above I cannot.

You cannot telnet to a port that has nothing listening on it. If apache is, for whatever reason failing to listed on port 443 and nothing else is listening on 443 then telnet will Connect failed exactly as above.
The netstat output in your question does indeed indicate nothing is listening on tcp 443.

It looks like my focus on ports is digressing from the fundamental problem - what do I need to change in order to enable https://... connection to a local (same computer) website. Retitle the question?
